# Linux Slackware ( Broken - kernel panic )

Tags: linux, kernel, kernel-panic, slackware, system-recovery

I wanted to update my system (Slackware current) which was in multilib. Before updating, I tried to remove all packages (compat32 and multilib). Big mistake !!! This have broken some crucial symlinks and give me now a kernel panic when i trie to boot it.

I have tried several methods, including this [one](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiPwpWJzYHSAhUiEpoKHbwvC2UQFggfMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Frlworkman.net%2Fhowtos%2Fglibc-recovery&usg=AFQjCNHgbFKdAevXmM5Ine2a0H6i6xHwVg&sig2=CaBgMWyDRGxylcoVzm4Cgw) But it does not work since I no longer have the original disc

Can someone tell me what is the proper way to recover the installation in this situation?

Comment: When something does that badly wrong, it's time to take the old penguin out back and install a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you can't boot your system, you need some other medium - cd or usb. there is no other magic way to boot unbootable system.

basically what you have to do is:

1. boot your machine (slackware installer).
2. mount your partitions and chroot to system `/` dir.
3. install packages you removed (download them from some slackware mirror and copy, ie on usb drive).

**in details:**

1. boot from slackware install disc or usb drive.
2. make some directory for your broken system (mount point), ie:

   ```
   mkdir /mnt
   ```
3. mount root partition (let's say it's `sda2`) to created directory, ie:

   ```
   mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
   ```
4. if your system is spread on many partitions (`/boot`, `/var` etc directory on separate partition) - mount them too! let's say your `/boot` is on `sda1` and `/var` on `sda3`:

   ```
   mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot
   mount /dev/sda3 /mnt/var
   ```
5. copy (ie on usb drive) packages you removed in some accessible place on your system partition, ie `/mnt/root`.
6. "switch" to your system partition:

   ```
   chroot /mnt
   ```
7. install packages, now they are in `/root`

**it is done :)**

next, to clean up:

8. exit chroot environment (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or `logout`).
9. umount partitions you mounted in 4. and then(!) 3, ie:

   ```
   umount /mnt/var
   umount /mnt/boot
   umount /mnt
   ```
10. reboot to your hopefully rescued slackware os :)

Comment: That's what I'm already trying to do. I have a swap (/dev/sda1) and (dev/sda2) for /. when mounting `mount /dev/sda2 /mnt` and `chroot /mnt /bin/bash -l` in mnt i have error: **chroot; failed to execute /bin/bash no such file or directory**. The install dvd is not the original, Is that this error comes from this?

Comment: when you chroot - you change your root partition and start new shell. for some reason there is no `/bin/bash` shell on your system. btw in most cases you don't have to specify `/bin/bash` when you chroot. by default chroot will use `/bin/sh` shell. please try `chroot /mnt`. if you get the same error, try with other shell, ie: `chroot /mnt /bin/zsh`. there are several other shells (`/bin/tcsh`, `/bin/zsh`, `/bin/ksh` etc), they are listed in `/etc/shells` file. one of them should work.

Comment: The problem is solved, that's what I said, it comes from the version. thank you for your help